# How to change output from call to media?

Tags: calls, discord

I call on Discord a lot and for a while was able to trick (I'd play a voice message and pause it before it ended) my phone into thinking the call was coming from a media source, so it would use media volume. This made everything sound high quality.
Unfortunately, this glitch has stopped working and now my calls sound tinny and distorted. Not solely in Discord, as well.

I was wondering how I could improve this and make things sound better again.

I have a TCL 408.